# All possible combinations used to generate relative abundances of said combinations from dataframe

Tags: r, loops, vector, bioinformatics, combinatorics

I'm trying to create a loop in R which calculates all possible combinations of all 20 amino acids without repetition in strings up to 20 characters long:

```
S <- c('G','A','L','M','F','W','K','Q','E','S','P','V','I','C','Y','H','R','N','D','T')



allCombs <- function(x) c(x, lapply(seq_along(x)[-1L], 
                                    function(y) combn(x, y, paste0, collapse = "")),
                          recursive = TRUE)
fu <- allCombs(S)
```

This code does this, but I also have a dataframe/csv which contains the relative proportions of the amino acids for 1000 different species, for example:

```
Species    G   A   L  ...
Species 1  0.1  0.2  0.4
Species 2  0.1  0.02 0.2
Species 3  0.0  0.09 0.01
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate what the proportion of each different combination of amino acids (G,A,L etc.) over the whole, i.e 1, is as vector/list/array.

The reason I'm doing this in R (rather than python) is because I want to do some interacting with other factors later on (which R is better suited to)

Apologies about how unclear this, I'm finding it quite difficult to explain, please let me know if I can be clearer, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you're trying to do. 1. You have all combinations. 2. You have a table where for each species you know what is the relative proportions of amino acid it has. e.g. One has 0.1 of G and 0.2 of A etc. 3. what is that your trying to do now?

Comment: I'm trying to combine the two, essentially adding the different combinations to the different proportions together, so A would be 0.1, then A,G 0.12... all the way to 20 (which would be 1) for each species

Comment: Could you please provide some sort of sample data?

Comment: So, Species 1: proportion of A = 0.1
                        prop of AG = 0.12
                        prop of AY = 0.123
                       ..through all 10 million combinations for each species (up to 20 amino acids)

Comment: Strain,A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,K,L,M,N,P,Q,R,S,T,V,W,Y

Acaryochloris_marina_MBIC11017,8.63062804444194, 1.20840792853488,5.1143291659966,5.70785002025175,3.47713995654374,7.19560864242886,2.18859035671376,6.67322000435096,4.21289868571883,11.7838509608676,2.30073830422317,3.24240318700859,5.06112649794611,5.16408509869107,4.88272286226009,5.82097877539072 2.51578453080204 7.70587135328063,1.21972869688864,2.51578453080204,

Comment: You basically trying to merge/match the tables?

Comment: I think it would be a for loop going through each combination, for each species, but I'm having trouble creating it in R, and if looping is the best way to go for this. Sorry for my poor clarity, I'm having trouble explaining myself well....

Comment: Yes a table would be great! Although really a variable storing each different prop(A), prop(AG) for each species would make more sense to me.

Comment: Essentially I need to derive a correlation between the proportion of (all combinations of amino acids and another variable, and then later on do a regression for a third variable.

Comment: Sounds to me like [reticulate](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/introduction.html) might be the solution here

Comment: Which function were you thinking specifically?

Comment: You seem to be approaching the problem as a python programmer would. `reticulate` would allow you to write python code to solve this problem, then use R for the downstream analyses within the same script. I would also suggest using a kmer counting library to count the number of occurrences of amino acid combinations of differing lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you'd do something like that:

```
require(tidyverse)
```

Your script, creating all combinations:

```
S <- c('G','A','L','M','F','W','K','Q','E','S','P','V','I','C','Y','H','R','N','D','T')

allCombs <- function(x) c(x, lapply(seq_along(x)[-1L], 
                                    function(y) combn(x, y, paste0, collapse = "")),
                          recursive = TRUE)
Scombi <- allCombs(S)
```

Creating sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
RelativeTable <- data.frame(replicate(length(allCombs(LETTERS[1:5])), sample(0:1,4,rep=TRUE))) %>% 
  purrr::set_names(allCombs(LETTERS[1:5]))

RelativeTable

  A B C D E AB AC AD AE BC BD BE CD CE DE ABC ABD ABE ACD ACE ADE BCD BCE BDE CDE ABCD ABCE ABDE ACDE BCDE ABCDE
1 0 1 1 1 0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1    1    0    0    0    1     1
2 1 0 0 1 0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0    0    1    0    1    1     0
3 0 1 1 0 0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0    0    1    1    1    1     0
4 1 1 0 1 1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1    1    1    0    0    0     0
```

Choosing from the `RelativeTable` only the combinations that we also have in `Scombi`

```
RelativeTable[, names(RelativeTable) %in%  Scombi]
```

Result:

```
 A C D E AC AD AE CD ACD
1 0 1 1 0  1  0  1  0   1
2 1 0 1 0  1  0  1  1   0
3 0 1 0 0  1  1  0  0   0
4 1 0 1 1  1  1  0  0   0
```

## Edit/explanation.

What I do here `RelativeTable[, names(RelativeTable) %in%  Scombi]` is basically two things.

1. I use the `%in%` which tells me if values in x are in y. The function returns a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE, and we can use it to see which combinations of amino acids appears in RelativeTable are in the combination vector.
   In addition, The function `names()` gives us the names of the columns.
   So, `names(RelativeTable) %in%  Scombi` (you can run just this statement), will give us a logical vector and will tell us if we have names in the relative table which are in the Scombi.
2. We can use the logical vector as indexes. Which mean, same idea as `RelativeTable[, 1]` would give us the first column, and `RelativeTable[, c(1,3)]` would give us the 1 and 3 columns, RelativeTable[, names(RelativeTable) %in%  Scombi] gives us only the "TRUE" columns - which means the columns that we want.

Comment: Yes that looks really useful! I will give it a go!

Comment: My newbishness with R is proving too much, how would I go about populating the table with the values from my imported dataframe?

Comment: I'm afraid it just crashes each time when I try and use my data, there are 10 million combinations of amino acids and my dataframe has 1000 different species in, I think its proving too much for R...

Comment: Haven't tried it myself, but as you're familiar with python but still want to use some parts of R, try using this:  https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate